# How to write generic method that receives a list and two BiFunction and evaluates expression?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I want to write a generic method that receives a `List l` and a two `BiFunction f1, f2` and returns the result of the following expression:

`(a0 + a1) * (a2 + a3) *...*(a_{n-1} + an) * an`.

Here `a1,...,an` are the elements of the given list and `+` denotes `f1`, and `*` denotes `f2`.

The logic part is pretty simple:

```
List<???> resF1 = new List<>(); //calculate result of f1 for each pair

for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i += 2) {
    resF1.add(f1.apply(l.get(i), l.get(i + 1)));
}

??? ans = f2.apply(resF1.get(0), resF1.get(1)); //get initial value of ans

for (int i = 2; i < resF1.size(); i++) {
    ans = f2.apply(ans, resF1.get(i)); //successively evaluate from left to right
}

ans = f2.apply(ans, l.get(l.size() - 1)); //don't forget about the last term of expr

return ans;
```

The hard part is to select generic types.

Let's start form method signature

`public static <F, S, T> ??? foo(List<? extends F> l, BiFunction<???, ???, ???> f1, BiFunction<???, ???, ???> f2)`

Let's assume that our function will have three generic types, so the types could be as common as possible.

I guess the type of list should be `<? extends F>`, since we want to read values from it and `? extends` is used just for that purpose.

As for `BiFunction`: since we are passing list elements to it, I guess the first two fields should be also `? extends F`. `? extends`, for the same reason as in list, but could we make it `? extends S` for `f1` and `? extends T` for `f2`?

It is also seems logical that the type of result of `f1` should be equal to the type of arguments of `f2`, since we applying it to `f2` to result of `f1`. However, there is the last term that contains the single element and it has `? extends F`, as we deduced earlier.

As for return value, I guess it should be either `T` or `U`.

So, how would you write such a method?

Comment: `public static <In, Out> Out foo(List<In> l, BiFunction<In, In, Out> f1, BiFunction<In, In, Out> f2)`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Shouldn't the type of result of `f1` be the same as argument type of `f2`?

Comment: Hm - maybe you're right. Add an `Inter`? Pass `Inter` out of `f1` and into `f2`?

Comment: Do you need the output to have a different type then the input?

Comment: @JornVernee Not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're overthinking this. Since the input and output type are the same, you only need one type variable (if they weren't, you'd need a third `BiFunction`).

In that case you can also use `BinaryOperator`, which is basically the equivalent of `BiFunction<T, T, T>`. The result is (copying your algorithm):

```
public static <T> T dualFold(List<T> l, BinaryOperator<T> f1, BinaryOperator<T> f2) {
    List<T> resF1 = new ArrayList<>(); //calculate result of f1 for each pair

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i += 2) {
        resF1.add(f1.apply(l.get(i), l.get(i + 1)));
    }

    T ans = f2.apply(resF1.get(0), resF1.get(1)); //get initial value of ans

    for (int i = 2; i < resF1.size(); i++) {
        ans = f2.apply(ans, resF1.get(i)); //successively evaluate from left to right
    }

    ans = f2.apply(ans, l.get(l.size() - 1)); //don't forget about the last term of expr

    return ans;
}
```